# How to label categorical variable in barplot?

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I developed a barplot for some data using python.How do you develop labels for the categorical values?

The data represents 0="Female" and 1="Male". The barplot developed shows only 0 and 1 but I want to represent as Female and Male.

Using the following code I got the below output:

```
sns.barplot(x=df.cp, y=df.chol, hue=df.sex, palette='spring')
plt.xlabel("Chest Pain Type")
plt.ylabel("Serum Cholesterol")
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

I tried adding this piece of code to the above but the output is not as expected and color differentiation is missing:

```
plt.legend(title="sex", loc="upper right", labels=["Female", "Male"])
```

[image: Output]

Thank you

Comment: What does `df` look like?

Comment: You should be able to do `sns.barplot(x="cp", y="chol", hue="sex", data=df)`.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of seaborn is mostly that you can directly use the columns of a dataframe. So the easiest solution to get the correct labels is to have those labels in the data you supply to the dataframe. E.g. having a dictionary that maps numbers to names

```
{1 : "male", 0 : "female"}
```

you can replace the data in the respective column before plotting:

```
sns.barplot(x="cp", y="chol", hue="sex", palette='spring', 
            data=df.replace({"sex" : {1 : "male", 0 : "female"}}))
```

Comment: Good answer, I clearly didn't process that the `sex` column wasn't categorical.

Comment: I tried using hue_order the labels are included but the bars are missing from the graph it's almost like an empty graph.

Comment: I doubt that hue_order is not working with *this* solution. (Note how it's different from the other answer). But if you experience further problems you can provide a [mcve].